# Get all products of a category in solr

Tags: php, magento, solr

I'm working with Magento CE 1.7 & Solr 4.6.0

Here you can see my goal,

When i search with a category name that should return all the products from that category, So how can i get this ?

For example, I have a category **Dresses** if i search with a word **dresses** that should return all of this category products

I tried like this `http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select/?q=4`  (category id :4)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select/?q=dresses
```

but its not giving any results.

Any ideas ?

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579630/search-by-category-name

Comment: @user2519904 I'm not looking directly with magento. i hope with solr is different than magento.